# ERROR: could not read block 131764 in file "base/22548/3826543.1": read only 0 of 8192 bytes

Tags: postgresql

I am getting error like below in postgresql and it have main column of `id` (primary key)(incremented using sequence).

If I click on column id then showing below error

```
ERROR:  could not read block 131764 in file "base/22548/3826543.1": read only 0 of 8192 bytes
```

I have some sub folders in base folder and I just move some files from one place to another place and then move to again same place and now getting this issue so what is the solution for this kind of issue?

For example:

```
mv base/22548/3826543.1 /usr/src/
mv /usr/src/3826543.1 base/22548/
```

Comment: ...Why would you do that?

Comment: I see that folder using huge memory so just try this way to clear out memory but then i have put back that all files but still its breaks.